# Problem adding canvas ( fabric.js) inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, fabricjs

> [Here are the errors I got :

[image]

Hello, please can someone help me solve the problem
adding canvas with `fabric.js` inside an `iframe`.

I have a button that allows me to add rectangles to a canvas.
I created the canvas object with `Fabric.js` that I added inside an `iframe` despite all the tests I did but it doesn't work.
You can see the errors obtained in the screenshot.
Can someone help me solve this problem please?

```html
    <html ><head >
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
    
    <title >monfabrick</title>
    <script src="fabric.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    
    var iframeDocument = document.getElementById('myiframe').contentWindow.document;
    var canvas = iframeDocument.getElementById('c');
    var fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvas);
    
    
            //var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
        // create a rect object
      var deleteIcon = "data:image/svg+xml,%3C%3Fxml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd'%3E%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Ebene_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='595.275px' height='595.275px' viewBox='200 215 230 470' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Ccircle style='fill:%23F44336;' cx='299.76' cy='439.067' r='218.516'/%3E%3Cg%3E%3Crect x='267.162' y='307.978' transform='matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -222.6202 340.6915)' style='fill:white;' width='65.545' height='262.18'/%3E%3Crect x='266.988' y='308.153' transform='matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 398.3889 -83.3116)' style='fill:white;' width='65.544' height='262.179'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E";
    
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = deleteIcon;
    
      fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
      fabric.Object.prototype.cornerColor = 'blue';
      fabric.Object.prototype.cornerStyle = 'circle';
    
      function Add() {
        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
          left: 100,
          top: 50,
          fill: 'yellow',
          width: 200,
          height: 100,
          objectCaching: false,
          stroke: 'lightgreen',
          strokeWidth: 4,
        });
    
        canvas.add(rect);
        canvas.setActiveObject(rect);
      }
    
      fabric.Object.prototype.controls.deleteControl = new fabric.Control({
        x: 0.5,
        y: -0.5,
        offsetY: 16,
        cursorStyle: 'pointer',
        mouseUpHandler: deleteObject,
        render: renderIcon,
        cornerSize: 24
      });
    
      Add();
    
      function deleteObject(eventData, target) {
            var canvas = target.canvas;
                canvas.remove(target);
            canvas.requestRenderAll();
        }
    
      function renderIcon(ctx, left, top, styleOverride, fabricObject) {
        var size = this.cornerSize;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(left, top);
        ctx.rotate(fabric.util.degreesToRadians(fabricObject.angle));
        ctx.drawImage(img, -size/2, -size/2, size, size);
        ctx.restore();
      }
    
            </script>
            
       <style type="text/css" __wid="U8TGjhvB">
     
              .controls {
        display: inline-block;
      }
    
    </style>
    
    </head>
    
    <body >
    
    <div class="controls" >
        <p >
          <button id="add" onclick="Add()" >Add a rectangle</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    
      <iframe src="http://localhost:7007/mapage/" name="moniframe" id="myiframe" contenteditable="true" width="400" height="400" class="embed-responsive-item" allowfullscreen __wid="tVriSNrP"> </iframe>
    
    </body></html>
```

Comment: If you run it outside of the iframe is it working? What version of fabric are you using?

Comment: Yes outside iframes it working.  V 3.6.3 (fabric.min.js)

Comment: Maybe in the iframe the version is different than the host. Because `facric.Control` is not a constructor implies that maybe it's not in the api yet.